# What if the number of task slot is greater than the task manager vcores

Tags: apache-flink

I have set `yarn.container.vcores=1` in the yaml configuration file, and I kick off a flink cluster with

`yarn-session.sh -jm 1024 -tm 2048 -n 4 -s 3`

With above command, I kick off 4 Task Managers, and each TM is allocated only 1 vcore, also each TM has 3 task slots.

Assume if I have 3 subtasks run in the TM, every task slot owns one sub task.

Could these 3 sub task run simultaneously with 3 threads(using 3 cpu cores, vcore=1 doesn't take effect) or they will concurrently with only one thread(vcore = 1 takes effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every task will have its own JVM thread, regardless of how many cores are available. It's fine if a task manager has 3 slots and 1 vcore. The tasks running in those slots will simply contend for the resources available to the TM.

Note that normally you will have several subtasks (or tasks -- [tasks and subtasks are really the same thing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/glossary.html#sub-task)) running in one slot. For each task slot to have only one subtask, either the job is super simple (i.e., a job graph with only one node), or you've done something special to isolate the subtasks.

Comment: Thanks @david. Then could I conclude: if the TM has 3 lots and 1 vcore, then actually the subtasks in these 3 slots will try to use at many as TM `cpu cores` to run these subtasks simultaneously?

Comment: Each (sub)task will have one JVM thread. All of the JVM threads in those 3 slots will compete for the 1 vcore available to the TM.

Comment: Note that Flink has no mechanism to ensure that really just one core is used. I know that K8s enforces it quite well, but last time that I check YARN was more reactively checking it (killed task after detecting RAM usage is higher than requested). Also note that it may depend on your very specific java version if it indeed just takes what is assigned https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242287.

Comment: From what I've read about how yarn enforces vcore limits, it uses linux cgroups to set a soft limit, expressed as a percentage of the total CPU. If additional CPU is available, yarn applications that want more CPU may be allowed to exceed their limits.

Comment: Thanks，the key point is how the task or subtask are sent to the TM.  assume that the TM has 3 slots and is allocated only 1 vocre, and there are totally 6 tasks/subtask to be run by these slots). if JM sent task to TM one by one(send next task when one is finished) ,then 1 vcore limit makes sense. If these 6 tasks are sent in the same time, then one vcore limit doesn't make sense.

Comment: That depends on whether it's batch or streaming -- Flink schedules batch and streaming differently, along the lines of what you've described. Obviously for streaming jobs, it's necessary to have all of the tasks running all of the time.